# Strange brackets in code I am reading

Tags: c++, square-bracket

What does it mean if I have in the middle of c++ code, things in brackets likt:

> [..]

What do these brackets mean?
is it cli?

Comment: Possibly your IDE has collapsed a code block for you. Try to click it.

Comment: can you post a snippet of the code where this appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably in your code editor and the purpose is to allow you to see more "context" code. Thus if you close a block of code you see more of what follows underneath.

Answer (score 1):

sorry in advance - not sure if this is too simple.

perhaps this is the subscript operator.

the primary use for this is to access a specific array element:

```
const int array[2] = {0,1};
const int value(array[0]); // access element 0 of `array`
```